# How did Iron Man record his past days?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-civil-war

In [*Captain America: Civil War* (2016)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3498820/), Iron Man demonstrates his product or something to people by presentic a holographic of his past days.

[image]

We can see young Tony Stark.

I know the movie is fiction, but this doesn't mean they had heavy technology in Tony Stark's past days. So how did he record this hologram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know the movie is fiction, but this doesn't mean they had heavy technology in Tony Stark's past days. So how did he record this hologram?

He recreated it based on his memories of the event...it's not an **actual** recording made at the time.

As I recall this was demo of *new* technology not a *replay* of the event.

It' s called Binarily Augumented Retro-Framing (B.A.R.F.) that "hijacks" the hippocampus to clear traumatic memories.

From the [**Wikia**](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/B.A.R.F.)

> The B.A.R.F. relies on an implant installed on a pair of glasses that connects with the user's hippocampus, allowing it to find a certain traumatic memory and alter it before projecting that memory onto an external infrastructure.

Comment: Implant. I don't think it means what they think it means.

Comment: Eh....an implant doesn't have to be in a body...it can be "a thing implanted in something else"...but it's vague at best.